# How to do rolling sum with conditional window criteria on different index levels in Python

Tags: python, group-by, rolling-sum

I want to do a rolling sum based on different levels of the index but am struggling to make it a reality. Instead of explaining the problem am giving below the demo input and desired output along with the kind of insights am looking for.

So I have multiple brands and each of their sales of various item categories in different year month day grouped by as below. What I want is a dynamic rolling sum at each day level, rolled over a window on Year as asked.

for eg, if someone asks

**Demo question 1) Till a certain day(not including that day) what were their last 2 years' sales of that particular category for that particular brand.**

**I need to be able to answer this for every single day i.e every single row should have a number as shown in Table 2.0.**

I want to be able to code in such a way that if the question changes from 2 years to 3 years I just need to change a number. **I also need to do the same thing at the month's level.**

**demo question 2) Till a certain day(not including that day) what was their last 3 months' sale of that particular category for that particular year for that particular brand.**

**Below is demo input**

*The tables are grouped by brand,category,year,month,day and sum of sales from a master table which had all the info and sales at hour level each day*

Table 1.0

| Brand | Category | Year | Month | Day | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Big Appliances | 2021 | 9 | 3 | 0 |
|  | Clothing | 2021 | 9 | 2 | 0 |
|  | Electronics | 2020 | 10 | 18 | 2 |
|  | Utensils | 2020 | 10 | 18 | 0 |
|  |  | 2021 | 9 | 2 | 4 |
|  |  |  |  | 3 | 0 |
| XYZ | Big Appliances | 2012 | 4 | 29 | 7 |
|  |  | 2013 | 4 | 7 | 6 |
|  | Clothing | 2012 | 4 | 29 | 3 |
|  | Electronics | 2013 | 4 | 9 | 1 |
|  |  |  |  | 27 | 2 |
|  |  |  | 5 | 4 | 5 |
|  |  | 2015 | 4 | 27 | 7 |
|  |  |  | 5 | 2 | 2 |
|  | Fans | 2013 | 4 | 14 | 4 |
|  |  |  | 5 | 4 | 0 |
|  |  | 2015 | 4 | 18 | 1 |
|  |  |  | 5 | 17 | 11 |
|  |  | 2016 | 4 | 12 | 18 |
|  | Furniture | 2012 | 5 | 4 | 1 |
|  |  |  |  | 8 | 6 |
|  |  |  |  | 20 | 4 |
|  |  | 2013 | 4 | 5 | 1 |
|  |  |  |  | 7 | 8 |
|  |  |  |  | 9 | 2 |
|  |  | 2015 | 4 | 18 | 12 |
|  |  |  |  | 27 | 15 |
|  |  |  | 5 | 2 | 4 |
|  |  |  |  | 17 | 3 |
|  | Musical-inst | 2012 | 5 | 18 | 10 |
|  |  | 2013 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
|  |  | 2015 | 4 | 16 | 10 |
|  |  |  |  | 18 | 0 |
|  |  | 2016 | 4 | 12 | 1 |
|  |  |  |  | 16 | 13 |
|  | Utencils | 2012 | 5 | 8 | 2 |
|  |  | 2016 | 4 | 16 | 3 |
|  |  |  |  | 18 | 2 |
|  |  | 2017 | 4 | 12 | 13 |

**Below is desired output for demo question 1 based on the demo table(last 2 years cumsum not including that day)**

Table 2.0

| Brand | Category | Year | Month | Day | Sales | Conditional Cumsum(till last 2 years) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Big Appliances | 2021 | 9 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
|  | Clothing | 2021 | 9 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
|  | Electronics | 2020 | 10 | 18 | 2 | 0 |
|  | Utensils | 2020 | 10 | 18 | 0 | 0 |
|  |  | 2021 | 9 | 2 | 4 | 0 |
|  |  |  |  | 3 | 0 | 4 |
| XYZ | Big Appliances | 2012 | 4 | 29 | 7 | 0 |
|  |  | 2013 | 4 | 7 | 6 | 7 |
|  | Clothing | 2012 | 4 | 29 | 3 | 0 |
|  | Electronics | 2013 | 4 | 9 | 1 | 0 |
|  |  |  |  | 27 | 2 | 1 |
|  |  |  | 5 | 4 | 5 | 3 |
|  |  | 2015 | 4 | 27 | 7 | 8 |
|  |  |  | 5 | 2 | 2 | 15 |
|  | Fans | 2013 | 4 | 14 | 4 | 0 |
|  |  |  | 5 | 4 | 0 | 4 |
|  |  | 2015 | 4 | 18 | 1 | 4 |
|  |  |  | 5 | 17 | 11 | 5 |
|  |  | 2016 | 4 | 12 | 18 | 12 |
|  | Furniture | 2012 | 5 | 4 | 1 | 0 |
|  |  |  |  | 8 | 6 | 1 |
|  |  |  |  | 20 | 4 | 7 |
|  |  | 2013 | 4 | 5 | 1 | 11 |
|  |  |  |  | 7 | 8 | 12 |
|  |  |  |  | 9 | 2 | 20 |
|  |  | 2015 | 4 | 18 | 12 | 11 |
|  |  |  |  | 27 | 15 | 23 |
|  |  |  | 5 | 2 | 4 | 38 |
|  |  |  |  | 17 | 3 | 42 |
|  | Musical-inst | 2012 | 5 | 18 | 10 | 0 |
|  |  | 2013 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 10 |
|  |  | 2015 | 4 | 16 | 10 | 6 |
|  |  |  |  | 18 | 0 | 16 |
|  |  | 2016 | 4 | 12 | 1 | 10 |
|  |  |  |  | 16 | 13 | 11 |
|  | Utencils | 2012 | 5 | 8 | 2 | 0 |
|  |  | 2016 | 4 | 16 | 3 | 0 |
|  |  |  |  | 18 | 2 | 3 |
|  |  | 2017 | 4 | 12 | 13 | 5 |

End thoughts:

The idea is to basically do a rolling window over year column maintaining the 2 years span criteria and keep on summing the sales figures.

P.S I really need a fast solution due to the huge data size and therefore created a .apply function row-wise which I didn't find feasible. A better solution by using some kind of group rolling sum or supporting columns will be really helpful.

Comment: What is the input type, is it a csv file or json?

Comment: input type can be any shoudnt effect the solution. take csv for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I'm giving a sample solution for the above problem.
I have concidered just onr product so that the solution would be simple

Code:

```
from datetime import date,timedelta
Input={"Utencils": [[2012,5,8,2],[2016,4,16,3],[2017,4,12,13]]}
Input1=Input["Utencils"]
Limit=timedelta(365*2)
cumsum=0
lis=[]
Tot=[]
for i in range(len(Input1)):
    if(lis):
        while(lis):
            idx=lis[0]
            Y,M,D=Input1[i][:3]
            reqDate=date(Y,M,D)-Limit
            Y,M,D=Input1[idx][:3]
            if(date(Y,M,D)<=reqDate):
                lis.pop(0)
                cumsum-=Input1[idx][3]
            else:
                break
    Tot.append(cumsum)
    lis.append(i)
    cumsum+=Input1[i][3]
print(Tot)
```

Here Tot would output the required cumsum column for the given data.
Output:

```
[0, 0, 3]
```

Here you can specify the Time span using Number of days in Limit variable.
Hope this solves the problem you are looking for.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the above method, I could give a much smaller code which would solve the above in fewer lines.

Comment: Hey just allow me some time to go through this and get back

Comment: Hey this looks good, to parse a dataframe having an additional index like in my example do i need to put that in a for loop first?

Comment: @DevrupBanerjee To use pd.read_csv(), you better have brand name and product name on every row. Then you could easily use df= pd.read_csv() and can get each product dataframe using, df[df['Brand"]=="ABC"] and df[df["Category"]=="Utencils"] to get only perticular rows which your require.

Comment: @DevrupBanerjee To add the cumsum column to you original dataframe use:                        df["Cumsum"] = list(that we calculated in above process)

Comment: @DevrupBanerjee If my answer solves your main problem do accept my answer so that I could get the bounty lol :)))

Comment: Hey just a small last thing, if instead of cumsum, like shown in the above code if I were to take the cumulative average, while every other principle of calculation remains the same, what must I change in the code?

Comment: @DevrupBanerjee Tot.append(cumsum/len(lis)) should work I guess in last 4th line